# How to receive data from mysql using socket module in python

Tags: python, mysql, sockets

How to receive data from mysql using socket module in python, i have try to import socket and connect it to mysql server for test, but have no data received from it, my code like this

```
def sender(data):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    host = '127.0.0.1'
    port = 3306

    sock.connect((host, int(port)))
    sock.sendall(data)
    sock.close()

def forward():
   host = '127.0.0.1'
   port = 9999
   s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
   s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1) 
   s.bind((host, int(port)))
   s.listen(10)
   sc, sockname = s.accept()
   data = sc.recv(8092)
   sender(data)
```

my destination is to forward data from my server to MySQL Server, how to correct this or anyone how to make it better, thank's

Comment: Use a mysql library capable of connecting to a remote database. [pymysql](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyMySQL) is one.

Comment: @msvalkon I think this is rather meant be a kind of port-forwarding / proxy mechanism. Am I right?!

Comment: You can use http://www.pymssql.org/ - A simple database interface for Python that builds on top of FreeTDS to provide a Python DB-API  interface to Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: @sebastian yes. this like a proxy server, i just want to forward data to mysql server, but i can't read data from my server, how to make it ?. thank's